# Redis key value pair size

Tags: redis

im trying to understand what is the size of the key value pair in redis if the key is 32 bytes and the value is a list with two 16 bytes?
In some cases (like postgres) there are different additional properties that are saved as part of the data it self.
Is there something similar in redis or is it just 64 bytes and thats it?